# Changing values in MergeSort in R

Tags: r, recursion, mergesort

Im trying to make MergeSort recursively in R. When I debug it, it seemed its not changing values as it is in Python. Any suggestions?

[image]

(Formating was not cooperating with me so I put picture here.)

Comment: It doesnt look like this function is returning something, you either need a  ```return(vector)``` or just  ```vector``` at the end.

Comment: @SebSta even if I add `return(vector)` it didnt help it.

Comment: Put it __before__ the last `}`. Like this: `} return(vector) }`

Comment: That is exactly what I did, but still, nothing changed. @Edward

Comment: Please try to copy and paste your function into the question. Select all, then press the {} button to format it.

Comment: You are also not assigning your first MergeSort calls to "left" and "right, you need to ```left <- MergeSort(left)``` and ```right <- MergeSort(right)```.

Comment: Thanks. That was to reason it was not working. It needed to be asigned. @SebSta

Comment: Youre welcome. In the future please try to provide code and not a screenshot as it helps significantly in reproducing the code/issues.

Comment: Is it faster than R's `sort` function?